# looking for UITableView With infinite scrolling , both up and down direction

Tags: uitableview, infinite-scroll

i want UITableView With infinite scrolling functionality, both the direction - upwards and downwards . the Data shown in table view are from mutable array.

its number between 1 to 10 and after 10. and then it should repeat the loop again from 1. without affecting the smoothness of scroll. Can anyone help me with the example code.
Thnks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not very clear on what you're asking.

Do you want to test a tableview by only having the numbers 1 to 10 repeating infinitely?

As in, are you trying to test with a mock implementation of using paging and getting ten records at a time?